# Dell Inspiron 5520 15R 12.04 LTS update

Tags: 12.04, updates, dell, inspiron

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 (with special driver support) on my Dell 5520 15R. [This](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201201-10377/) Ubuntu image was recommended, as the system is Ubuntu certified. The hardware is exactly as the link states.

Anyway, installation went fine, no problems there. However, after downloading and installing the latest updates, the system practically destabilized.

The first thing I noticed was random system "freeze-ups", after which I had to manually power off the PC (hold power button) Next were the HDD as well as the external USB3.0 HDD which didn't spin down, nor power off (not even --detach would work).

I reinstalled, didn't update and everything is working fine again.

Are system updates incompatible with this "special" Ubuntu image? Will another update attempt yield the same results?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is a very generic question. Try to split into individual problems to have answers for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got my results... the hard way. Did an update and got the same issues.

Made some further research and came to the conclusion that AMD does NOT support its graphic adapters after Ubuntu 12.04 (not even 12.04.1) hence - the freeze ups.

As for the USB3.0 external HDD, well, [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/792085) explains it. (I guess)

So to make this short: NO, updates are NOT compatible with the special image.

Answer (score 0):

As a general answer: no problems in updating Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have the same notebook you have and used 12.04 for a time, updating that, and did not face these problems. Perhaps you are having some issues that are solvable.